# Why named flux in react?

Tags: reactjs, flux

I searched this question, but I could not find any information.

Why called flux? Not technical means.

Help me plz.

blow, I searched Flux

- https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html
- https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview.html#content

Comment: Flux is all about uni-directional data flow in react. And in english Flux also means the action or process of flowing or flowing out. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Yes. Could you tell me more official reference site or blog?

Comment: Well, you can read about flux in the links you posted in your question and Google the meaning of Flux. Facebook doesn't have any official doc regarding why it named Flux as Flux.

Comment: thanks for your help.